# Apache poi xlsx file with unsaved changes

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I'am facing  a wierd behaviours  when creating excel spreadsheets with poi. I am able to save contents  but  when i  open it on excel and try to close the document whitout touching it  i get a messagebox   with a message along the lines of "would you like to save your modifications".

code :

```
protected static Map< String ,CellStyle> makeCellStyles(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        Map<String , CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<String , CellStyle>();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LAVENDER.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        font.setBold(true);
        style.setFont(font);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        styles.put("groupHeader", style);
        style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        font.setBold(true);
        style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE_GREY.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setFont(font);
        styles.put("rowHeader", style);
        DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
        style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("# ##0"));
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        styles.put("borderData", style);
        style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        //style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("# ##0"));
        styles.put("data", style);
        return styles;
    }

    static private void writeXls() {
        // Using XSSF for xlsx format, for xls use HSSF
        //final String FILE_PATH = "F:/lesStats.xlsx";
        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(statfile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
            String si = "Fichier;total documents; documents corrects;"
                + "documents erronnees; erreurs formats ; "
                + "erreur dictionnaire ; erreurs index manquants ; erreurs chemin";
            String[] entetes = si.split(";");
            Sheet globalStat = workbook.createSheet("statistiques gobales");
            setXlsProperties(workbook);
            int cellIndex = 0;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            Row row = globalStat.createRow(rowIndex++);
            row = globalStat.createRow(rowIndex++);
            row = globalStat.createRow(rowIndex++);
            Map<String ,CellStyle> styles = makeCellStyles(workbook);


            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (i != 4)
                    row.createCell(i).setCellValue("");
                else {
                    row.createCell(i).setCellValue("Type Erreurs");
                }
            }

            for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
                row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(styles.get("groupHeader"));
                // row.getCell(i).getCellStyle().setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

            }
            row.getCell(7).getCellStyle().setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
                // (groupHeaderStyle);
            globalStat.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 4, 7));
            // row.getCell(4).setCellStyle(groupHeaderStyle);
            row = globalStat.createRow(rowIndex++);
            cellIndex = 0;

            for (String val : entetes) {

                row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(val);
                row.getCell(cellIndex - 1).setCellStyle(styles.get("rowHeader"));
            }

            int fileIndex = 0;

            for (Integer[] info : lesstats) {
                row = globalStat.createRow(rowIndex++);
                cellIndex = 0;
                row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(filescecked.get(fileIndex++));
                row.getCell(0).setCellStyle(styles.get("rowHeader"));
                for (Integer i : info) {

                    row.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(i);
                    row.getCell(cellIndex).setCellStyle(styles.get("data"));
                    cellIndex++;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(lesstats.size());
            for (int i = 1; i <= lesstats.get(0).length; i++) {
                row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(styles.get("borderData"));
            }

            row = globalStat.createRow(rowIndex);
            row.createCell(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                row.createCell(i);

                Integer limit = 3 + lesstats.size();
                String col = "";
                col += (char) (65 + i);
                col += "3";
                col += ":";
                col += (char) (65 + i);
                col += limit.toString() + ")";
                System.out.println("\tSUM(" + col);

                row.getCell(i).setCellFormula("SUM(" + col);
                row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(styles.get("rowHeader"));
                row.getCell(i).getCellStyle().setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
                row.getCell(i).getCellStyle().setDataFormat(format.getFormat("# ##0"));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                globalStat.autoSizeColumn(i);
            //workbook.close();
            workbook.write(fos);

            fos.close();
            workbook.close();
            System.out.println(statfile + " is successfully written");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've just discovered that if  i remove the call to setCellFormula  the issue disappears which doesnt  make any sense.

Comment: I don't think you actually need to call workbook.close()...